# Nuget packages included in artifacts automatically

Tags: nuget, teamcity, octopus-deploy

We have a TeamCity build server and for a time were had the internal Nuget server enabled.  We'd generate Nuget packages, which it'd automatically publish to the nuget feed.

We've since moved to another Nuget server and disabled the TC internal Nuget server; additionally we started building Nuget packages using OctoPack in some configurations which never built them before.  The problem is that these Nuget packages seem to automatically be added to the build configuration's Artifacts.  This is a waste, since the same packages are being published to the external (to TeamCity) Nuget server.

Is there a setting which automatically will find and include Nuget packages in TeamCity's artifacts, or is it just doing this on its own?  I cant even explicitly exclude the packages in the configuration's artifacts setting, they get included regardless.

TeamCity is version 2018.1.2.

Comment: If your `Artifacts Path` is set correctly. Can you try to reset relevant `cache` elements or create an entirely new Build Configuration and see if it the issue is reproducible. Warning: If you are trying to reset `cache` do it at your own risk since can have adverse effects.

Answer (score 0):

New packages in built-in TeamCity NuGet feeds could be added via the [followings ways](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCDL/Using+TeamCity+as+NuGet+Feed#UsingTeamCityasNuGetFeed-IndexingNuGetPackages).

So to avoid publishing produced nuget packages as a build artifacts inspect:

- [Artifact paths](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCDL/Configuring+General+Settings#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-ArtifactPaths) settings in your build configuration
- [NuGet Pack](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCDL/NuGet+Pack) build steps settings: uncheck "Publish created packages to build artifacts" option
- [NuGet Publish](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCDL/NuGet+Publish) build steps settings: don't specify TeamCity built-in NuGet feed URLs in "Package source" field.

Comment: The built-in Nuget feed is disabled everywhere.  Artifact paths are currently set to explicit *exclude* Nuget packages, but seems to be ignored.  We're not using Nuget Pack or Publish either.